# Boundedness of the quotient tail end / general term of a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_n u_n$ be a convergent series with $u_n \geq 0$ and let $R_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty u_k$ be its tail end, which converges to $0$. I am looking for nontrivial sufficient conditions for the sequence $\frac{R_n}{u_n}$ to be bounded. This is obviously the case if $u_{n+1} \leq \lambda u_n$ for all $n$ with $\lambda < 1$, but there are also  counterexamples where $\frac{R_n}{u_n} \rightarrow \infty$  (such as $u_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$). Any ideas appreciated.